# Check if variable is a Response object or normal object

Tags: javascript, response, fetch-api

Is it possible to check if a variable is a *[Resonse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) type* object vs a normal object?

I have tried to use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), but both cases end in the object. I also tried to do [`Object.keys(myVar)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). This gives me an empty array on Response and keys on the object. This could work, but I hope there is a better way to distinguish both.

```js
let myVar

if (something) {
    myVar = { someKey: someValue }
} else {
    myVar = new Response(...)
}

// check if myVar is a Response or an object...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`instanceOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator for this purpose:

```js
something = false
let myVar

if (something) {
    myVar = { someKey: someValue }
} else {
    myVar = new Response()
}


console.log('IsResponse:', myVar instanceof Response)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the properties that exist only in `Response`.
See below

```js
let myVar

if (something) {
    myVar = { someKey: someValue }
} else {
    myVar = new Response()
}

if (myVar.body && myVar.headers)
  console.log("Response", true)
 else   console.log("Response", false)
```